# Turning off Eclipse's guidance

Tags: eclipse, syntax, editor

So basically I want to drive myself crazy while disciplining myself learning to program. I want to kick it old school and really understand what I'm doing. I don't want Eclipse to hold my hand and tell me that I have a syntax error or that I have any errors except for when I run my code and the console tells me something is wrong. I have searched and searched and searched online and I cannot find where you disable anything. I've been to the editor/compiler preferences and changed everything to **ignore** instead of **warning**, but eclipse is still holding my hand.

I'm using Eclipse Luna for Java. Any suggestions or help at all would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Suggestion: Do not turn off the build automatically feature from Project menu, because that helps with faster development, learning. BTW: that is one of the things you are looking for (and I still do not recommend.)

Answer (score 1):

The closest I think you'll get is to disable the automatic, incremental compilation (menu **Project** > **Build Automatically**). But that doesn't disable the Java editor's natural tendency to highlight obvious syntactical errors as you type.

To be honest, if you really want to avoid all of the guidance that an IDE like Eclipse gives you, you'd probably be better off using a "plain" text editor (possibly with simple syntax coloring), such as TextPad or Notepad++, along with command-line `javac`. But I don't think that will actually help you learn better; it certainly doesn't help with the exploratory/discovery part of learning.